# phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner freeze on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm using ionic version 1.7.12 with the plugin phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner version 4.1.0 on OSX 10.11.2, additional node version is v0.10.26 and cordova 5.4.1 testing on IOS 6+, after my projects compile and install the ipa on the testing device when i try to open the scanner it freeze the app, something to add this is a legacy app.

The estrange thing its that if i start a new project from scratch using ionic cli and and install the plugin it works just fine.

Any place where i should look or what im doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "freeze"? i have similar problem, when i toggle bar code scanner with a button clicked, it open up a camera view and freeze, and by "freeze" i mean a image toked by the camera and not moving(you can still click cancel button and return back to the view).

i found out the button click event has toggle twice with one click and it explained why you have a image not moving.

i solved this problem by working around.

```
$scope.scannerActive = false;
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
    if(!$scope.scannerActive) {
        $scope.scannerActive = true;
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(
            function(result) {
                if (!result.cancelled) {
                    console.log(result)
                }
                else {
                    console.log('cancelled')
                }
            },function(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }).finally(function() {
                $scope.scannerActive = false;
            });
        });
    }
};
```